# What is the average size of a packet sent via TCP/Ethernet?

Tags: networking

A message isn't sent in it's entirety - it's broken up into little packets of data, each one going to a specific destination. But how little are those packets? I can't find the answer on Google.

Comment: This question cannot be answered. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: [Here's the answer](http://superuser.com/questions/964682/what-is-the-average-size-of-a-packet-sent-via-tcp-ethernet/964685?noredirect=1#comment1640442_964685) along with a visual of [how an Ethernet packed is structured](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6LNLB.png)

Answer (score 4):

The average size of the packet would depend on the application.   @DrZoo is largely right - a typical packet on the internet is 1476 - 1500 bytes, however bigger or smaller packets are possible.

This answer does not take into account when a small amount of data is sent in a packet - for example in a chat session.  Also, when downloading something like a webpage, the last packet relating to each connection would not be full.    I'd guess the average packet for TCP is somewhere in the region of 1400 bytes - but if you are talking about tcp/ip its a lot lower - things like games, voip etc often use a lot of very small packets.

Comment: Right, it's hard to tell what the average size of a packet is, because the size of data is so dynamic. I added a picture to my answer to help visualize an Ethernet packet.